# Xcode 14 build successful, but getting "Could not communicate with a helper application" when trying to run on iPhone device

Tags: xcode

Build in Xcode is successful, and it goes to launch on my device and gives the error described below.

It is a Flutter application, but not sure this is relevant, and the issue only started happening after upgrade to Xcode 14. I can build and deploy the app to TestFlight just fine, but I can not run the app on my device from Xcode which means doing any kind of debugging of the app is extremely difficult.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode multiple times from suggestions in other questions in StackOverflow, but it has not fixed the issue.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q22sa.png)

When I view details, it says this:

```
Details

Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 4099
Recovery Suggestion: Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-09-29 15:40:53 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.companionappd was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.";
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,3";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.6.1 (19G82)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 23;
    "operation_errorCode" = 4099;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSCocoaErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.6 (Build 21G115)
Xcode 14.0.1 (21336) (Build 14A400)
Timestamp: 2022-09-29T08:40:53-07:00
```

Anyone have ideas on how to fix this? Been searching for answers for a couple days now.